# tramp multi hops and known_hosts

Tags: tramp

I'm using tramp to access files in remote via Bastion server using following tramp syntax:

```
    /ssh:root@BASTION-HOST#BASTION-PORT|root@REAL-HOST#REAL-PORT:
```

The problem is, whenever I access REAL-HOST, `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` in BASTION-HOST is updated.  Since most hosts behind the BASTION-HOST are ephemeral, I don't want TRAMP update `known_hosts` file.

After looking at `tramp-methods`, TRAMP does uses `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` on the first host (which is BASTION in this case), but it looks like these options do not propagates to multi-hops.

I'm using Emacs 25.1.1 (Mac)

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I'm even not sure they are used with the first hop. I've just checked with Emacs 25.2 (as installed with Ubuntu 17.10), And I couldn't find these arguments in the traces.

IIRC, these options are used only for the `tunnel` and `socks` methods. That's why the argument in `tramp-methods` is called `tramp-gw-args`. Note, that the upcoming Emcs 26.1 (Tramp 2.3) does not support these gateway methods any longer.

Your best guess would be to define an own method in `tramp-methods`, adding these arguments to `tramp-login-args`.